# Can girls dance in islam for a school programme?

Tags: halal-haram, school

Assalamualaikum,
  Im a muslim girl, 15 years old. Every year we have annual day celebrations which is full of dances and dramas performed separately by boys and girls. This year I was planning to join a dance perfomance. Absolutely we are planning to cover our body as per islam asks us to.. But one of my friend says that dancing is haram. I would like to know that 'is dancing haram in such a situation'.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and our model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Dancing for your husband is something permissible any thing else is at least makrooh or haraam.